# How does GCP count new users for unverified apps?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, verification

I have a Google Cloud Project that has some advertisement APIs enabled (DCM, SA360).
I use these with http in Excel/VBA.
I am pretty much the only person who logs in, there may be about 2-3 other logins.
I also have a Google Apps Script that uses a refresh token to access the APIs on my behalf.

Recently I got the unverified app screen - reading online this doesn't seem to be a problem for a small team.

However, I also got an email from Google saying that I've already expended 60% of the 100 new user quota for unverified apps - which is surprising, because I am confident that I don't have any actual new users.

What counts as a new user? Does the Google Apps Script, accessing from different google IPs, count as a new user everytime it fires?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Google is using unique email addresses. However, in my own apps I think is more like just accesses. Google is tightening what apps can do. Here is a link that I am still reviewing: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/06/gmails-api-lockdown-will-kill-some-third-party-app-access-starting-july-15/

Comment: ... wow. Not good news, Drive API access is something I wanted to get involved with too.